# Marketing Cloud Journey Builder - Logic when using contact data evaluation

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a Journey where it does a decision split based on a Data Extension Status field = Planned. I am using the "contact data" evaluation option as the status can change from the time the person is initially injected into the journey.

Eg: Person enters the journey as status = planned however along the way have their status changed to cancelled or rescheduled.

Based on these changes the person will take a different route.

When using contact data i get this message *"At least one attribute in this filter criteria could produce multiple matching values. By default, Journey Builder uses the first matching value. You can use attribute-to-attribute comparison to determine the right match"*

I have a primary key based on the event ID so this is unique and will only be in the data once, however a person could be in the Data Extension multiple times over the period of a year with different Event ID's.

My Question is when the Journey does a match to check the record is it based on the Data Extension primary key or Subscriber key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact Data always uses `contactkey` to lookup to the data extension using the field you linked to `contactkey` in data designer. If you have a 1:N of `contactkey` to `status`, you need to leverage '[Attribute to Attribute comparison](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_attribute_comparison.htm&type=5)', where you use `eventid` from Journey Data to `eventid` field in the Contact Data data extension

Comment: So just to make sure im reading the Attribute to Attribute comparison if i use EventId = EventID and Status = Planned then it should work correctly?

Comment: Yeah, its best to think of it like a sql statement where select top 1 status from DE where contactkey = contactkeyin journey and eventid= eventidfromjourney

Comment: Great thanks for your help